# Настройка Git для OpenServer и Composer

Tags: git, php, openserver, composer, symfony2

Всем доброго дня. Уже неделю мучаюсь, не могу установить Composer через Git. У кого удачно получилось справится с установкой, не могли бы вы описать как нужно действовать?
В моем случае при команде

```
php composer.phar install
```

вылезает ошибка

```
 [ErrorException]

  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Roaming/Composer/.htaccess) is not within the allowed path(s): (W:/domains;W:/userdata/temp;W:/modules/system/html/openserver;)

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-c
ustom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--opt
imize-autoloader]
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моё решение: [Установка Composer в OpenServer](http://plutov.by/post/composer_openserver).

> Статьи с решением этой проблемы я не нашел и стал задумываться, почему
>   же не видно модуля ssl? Одним из вопросов, который я задал сам себе,
>   был таким - "А тот ли конфиг использует PHP, который используется
>   Composer’ом?" Это был верный вектор, через какое-то время оказалось,
>   что PHP, запущенный из командной строки использует не тот php.ini,
>   который я изменял, для CLI есть свой конфиг. Но его нигде нет, я
>   облазил все папки OpenServer'а. Оказывается, для CLI конфиг всегда
>   ищется в C:/Windows. Было решено скопировать туда php.ini, а еще
>   лучше, сделать ссылку на файл, редактируемый нами.
>   `mklink C:\Windows\php.ini C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\config\php.ini`
>   После этого я удачно установил Composer, настроил зависимости.

Answer (score 1):

Отличный курс по Git & Composer качал здесь http://infosklad.org/threads/git-composer-polnyj-komplekt-uroki-1-12.8124/ кому надо забирайте